# X3D in viewer using X3DOM

Tags: x3d

I had the following code working in X3D viewers but am now trying to get running in a web browser (Google Chrome) using X3DOM (http://x3dom.org/). I get nodes but not links; some text appears as errors.

Maybe some X3DOM programmer can look at and tell me how to fix.  I think I am close.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <!-- FileName:         nodeLinkToggleExtrusion.xhtml              --> 
    <!--                                                              --> 
    <!-- Description:      dynamic scene graph of nodes and link(s):  -->
    <!--                     node toggle of text,                     -->
    <!--                     link toggle of text,                     -->
    <!--                     extrusion of link(s) between nodes,      -->
    <!--                     animation of packet exchange using       -->
    <!--                     ROUTE mechanism between nodes.           -->
    <!--                   node geometry are spheres using            -->
    <!--                     cylinders for link extrusion.            -->
    <!--                                                              --> 
    <!-- By:               Andrew M. Neiderer.                        --> 
    <!--                                                              --> 
    <!-- Reference:        Sergey Bederov, Parallel Graphics, Inc.    -->
    <!--                    for link extrusion and                    -->
    <!--                    packet exchange between nodes.            -->
    <!--                                                              -->
    <!-- Date:             7 July 2020.                               --> 

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
          content="chrome=1"/> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
          content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          src="http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom.js"/> 
    <!--          href="/home/andrewmneiderer/lib/x3dom.css"/>  -->

    <script type="text/ecmascript"  
            src="http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom.js"/> 
    <!--            src="/home/andrewmneiderer/lib/x3dom.js"/> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <X3D profile="Immersive" version="3.1">
      <Scene> 
        <!-- node 1 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_node1"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_node1"  
                     translation="-2.0 2.0 -2.0"> 
            <Shape DEF="SHAPE_node"> 
              <Appearance> 
                <Material DEF="MATERIAL_node" 
                          diffuseColor="1.0 0.0 0.0" 
                          transparency="0.3"/> 
              </Appearance> 

              <Sphere/> 
            </Shape> 

            <!-- toggle text on the node --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_node1"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.5 -0.75 -0.5"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_node"/> 
                  </Appearance> 

                  <Text DEF="TEXT_node1" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="node 1"> 
                    <FontStyle DEF="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink" 
                               containerField="fontStyle" 
                               family='"SERIF"' 
                               horizontal="true" 
                               justify='"BEGIN"' 
                               leftToRight="true" 
                               size="1.0" 
                               spacing="1.0" 
                               style="PLAIN" 
                               topToBottom="true"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 
          </Transform> 

          <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_node1"  
                       offset="-2.0 2.0 -2.0"/> 
          <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_node1" enabled="true"/> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node1"> 
          <field name="touch_node" type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_node" type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_node" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                                    value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_node() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_node ) { 
                                  onOff_node  = 1; 
                                  active_node = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_node  = 0; 
                                  active_node = true; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- node 2 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_node2"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_node2"  
                     translation="0.0 -2.0 0.0"> 
            <Shape USE="SHAPE_node"/> 

            <!-- toggle text on the node --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_node2"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.5 -0.75 -0.5"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_node"/> 
                  </Appearance> 

                  <Text DEF="TEXT_node2" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="node 2"> 
                    <FontStyle USE="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 
          </Transform> 

          <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_node2"   
                       offset="0.0 -2.0 0.0"/> 
          <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_node2" enabled="true"/> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node2"> 
          <field name="touch_node" type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_node" type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_node" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                 value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_node() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_node ) { 
                                  onOff_node  = 1; 
                                  active_node = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_node  = 0; 
                                  active_node = true; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- node 3 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_node3"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_node3"   
                     translation="2.0 2.0 2.0"> 
            <Shape USE="SHAPE_node"/> 

            <!-- toggle text on the node --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_node3"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.5 -0.75 -0.5"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_node"/> 
                  </Appearance> 

                  <Text DEF="TEXT_node3" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="node 3"> 
                    <FontStyle USE="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 
          </Transform> 

          <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_node3"   
                       offset="2.0 2.0 2.0"/> 
          <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_node3" enabled="true"/> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node3"> 
          <field name="touch_node" type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_node" type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_node" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                 value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_node() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_node ) { 
                                  onOff_node  = 1; 
                                  active_node = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_node  = 0; 
                                  active_node = true; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- link from node 1 to node 2 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_link_1_2"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_link_1_2" 
                     translation="0.0 0.0 0.0"> 
            <Shape DEF="SHAPE_link_1_2"> 
              <Appearance > 
                <Material DEF="MATERIAL_link" 
                          diffuseColor="0.0 0.3 1.0"/> 
              </Appearance> 

              <Extrusion DEF="EXTRUSION_link_1_2"   
                         crossSection=" 0.1  0.2,   
                                        0.2  0.0,  
                                        0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.2  0.0,  
                                       -0.1  0.2,  
                                        0.1  0.2"  
                         solid="false"  
                         creaseAngle="1.2"  
                         spine="-2.0  2.0 -2.0,  
                                 0.0 -2.0  0.0"/> 
            </Shape> 

            <!-- toggle text on the link --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_link_1_2"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.0 0.0 -1.0"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_link"/> 
  
                  <Text DEF="TEXT_link_1_2" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="link from node 1 to node 2"> 
                    <FontStyle USE="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 

            <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_link_1_2" 
                         offset="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> 
            <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_1_2" enabled="true"/> 
          </Transform> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_1_2"> 
          <field name="touch_link"  type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_link"  type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_link" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                 value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_link() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_link ) { 
                                  onOff_link =  1; 
                                  active_link = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_link =  false; 
                                  active_link = 1; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
             </Appearance> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- dynamic link from node 1 to node 2 --> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_link_1_2"> 
          <field name="translationA"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="translationZ"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine"         type="MFVec3f"  
                                      value="-2.0  2.0 -2.0,  
                                              0.0 -2.0  0.0"  
                                                     accessType="initializeOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine_changed" type="MFVec3f" accessType="outputOnly"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 
                              function translationA(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[0] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 

                              function translationZ(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[1] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 
              ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- link from node 2 to node 3 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_link_2_3"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_link_2_3" 
                     translation="0.0 0.0 0.0"> 
            <Shape DEF="SHAPE_link_2_3"> 
              <Appearance > 
                <Material USE="MATERIAL_link"/> 
              </Appearance> 

              <Extrusion DEF="EXTRUSION_link_2_3"   
                         crossSection=" 0.1  0.2,   
                                        0.2  0.0,  
                                        0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.2  0.0,  
                                       -0.1  0.2,  
                                        0.1  0.2"  
                         solid="false"  
                         creaseAngle="1.2"  
                         spine=" 0.0 -2.0  0.0,  
                                 2.0  2.0  2.0"/> 
            </Shape> 

            <!-- toggle text on the link --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_link_2_3"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.0 0.0 -1.0"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_link"/> 
                  </Appearance> 

                  <Text DEF="TEXT_link_2_3" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="link from node 2 to node 3"> 
                    <FontStyle USE="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 

            <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_link_2_3" 
                         offset="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> 
            <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_2_3" enabled="true"/> 
          </Transform> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_2_3"> 
          <field name="touch_link"  type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_link"  type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_link" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                 value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_link() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_link ) { 
                                  onOff_link =  1; 
                                  active_link = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_link =  false; 
                                  active_link = 1; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- dynamic link from node 2 to node 3 --> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_link_2_3"> 
          <field name="translationA"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="translationZ"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine"         type="MFVec3f"  
                                      value=" 0.0 -2.0  0.0,  
                                              2.0  2.0  2.0"  
                                                    accessType="initializeOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine_changed" type="MFVec3f" accessType="outputOnly"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 
                              function translationA(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[0] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 

                              function translationZ(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[1] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 
              ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- link from node 3 to node 1 --> 

        <Group DEF="GROUP_link_3_1"> 
          <Transform DEF="TRANSFORM_link_3_1" 
                     translation="0.0 0.0 0.0"> 
            <Shape DEF="SHAPE_link_3_1"> 
              <Appearance > 
                <Material USE="MATERIAL_link"/> 
              </Appearance> 

              <Extrusion DEF="EXTRUSION_link_3_1"   
                         crossSection=" 0.1  0.2,   
                                        0.2  0.0,  
                                        0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.1 -0.2,  
                                       -0.2  0.0,  
                                       -0.1  0.2,  
                                        0.1  0.2"  
                         solid="false"  
                         creaseAngle="1.2"  
                         spine=" 2.0  2.0  2.0, 
                                -2.0  2.0 -2.0"/> 
            </Shape> 

            <!-- toggle text on the link --> 

            <Switch DEF="SWITCH_link_3_1"> 
              <Transform translation="-1.0 0.0 -1.0"> 

                <!-- appearance and text --> 

                <Shape> 
                  <Appearance> 
                    <Material USE="MATERIAL_link"/> 
                  </Appearance> 

                  <Text DEF="TEXT_link_3_1" 
                        containerField="geometry" 
                        maxExtent="0.0" 
                        string="link from node 3 to node 1"> 
                    <FontStyle USE="FONT_STYLE_nodeAndLink"/> 
                  </Text> 
                </Shape> 
              </Transform> 
            </Switch> 

            <PlaneSensor DEF="PLANE_SENSOR_link_3_1" 
                         offset="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> 
            <TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_3_1" enabled="true"/> 
          </Transform> 
        </Group> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_3_1"> 
          <field name="touch_link"  type="SFTime"  accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="onOff_link"  type="SFInt32" accessType="outputOnly"/> 
          <field name="active_link" type="SFBool" accessType="initializeOnly" 
                 value="false"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 

                              function touch_link() 
                              { 
                                if ( active_link ) { 
                                  onOff_link =  1; 
                                  active_link = false; 
                                } 
                                else { 
                                  onOff_link =  false; 
                                  active_link = 1; 
                                } 
                              } 
                  ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- dynamic link from node 3 to node 1 --> 

        <Script DEF="SCRIPT_link_3_1"> 
          <field name="translationA"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="translationZ"  type="SFVec3f" accessType="inputOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine"         type="MFVec3f"  
                                      value=" 2.0  2.0  2.0, 
                                             -2.0  2.0 -2.0"  
                                                     accessType="initializeOnly"/> 
          <field name="spine_changed" type="MFVec3f" accessType="outputOnly"/> 

          <![CDATA[ecmascript: 
                              function translationA(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[0] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 
                              function translationZ(value) 
                              { 
                                spine[1] = value; 

                                spine_changed = spine; 
                              } 
              ]]> 
        </Script> 

        <!-- animation --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="PLANE_SENSOR_node1"        fromField="translation_changed"  
               toNode=  "TRANSFORM_node1"           toField=  "translation"/> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="PLANE_SENSOR_node2"        fromField="translation_changed"  
               toNode=  "TRANSFORM_node2"           toField=  "translation"/> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="PLANE_SENSOR_node3"        fromField="translation_changed"  
               toNode=  "TRANSFORM_node3"           toField=  "translation"/> 

                                                    <!-- node 1 toggle --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_node1"        fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node1"  toField=  "touch_node"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node1"  fromField="onOff_node" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_node1"              toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!-- node 2 toggle --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_node2"        fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node2"  toField=  "touch_node"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node2"  fromField="onOff_node" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_node2"              toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!-- node 3 toggle --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_node3"        fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node3"  toField=  "touch_node"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_node3"  fromField="onOff_node" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_node3"              toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!-- toggle link from node 1 to node 2 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_1_2"       fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_1_2" toField=  "touch_link"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_1_2" fromField="onOff_link" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_link_1_2"             toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!-- toggle link from node 2 to node 3 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_2_3"       fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_2_3" toField=  "touch_link"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_2_3" fromField="onOff_link" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_link_2_3"             toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!-- toggle link from node 3 to node 1 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TOUCH_SENSOR_link_3_1"       fromField="touchTime" 
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_3_1" toField=  "touch_link"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_touchSwitch_link_3_1" fromField="onOff_link" 
               toNode=  "SWITCH_link_3_1"             toField=  "whichChoice"/> 

                                                    <!--   link extrusion(s) for node 1 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node1"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_1_2"           toField=  "translationA"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_1_2"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_1_2"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node1"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_3_1"           toField=  "translationZ"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_3_1"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_3_1"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 

                                                    <!--   link extrusion(s) for node 2 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node2"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_2_3"           toField=  "translationA"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_2_3"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_2_3"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node2"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_1_2"           toField=  "translationZ"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_1_2"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_1_2"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 

                                                    <!--   link extrusion(s) for node 3 --> 

        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node3"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_3_1"           toField=  "translationA"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_3_1"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_3_1"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="TRANSFORM_node3"           fromField="translation"  
               toNode=  "SCRIPT_link_2_3"           toField=  "translationZ"/> 
        <ROUTE fromNode="SCRIPT_link_2_3"           fromField="spine_changed"  
               toNode=  "EXTRUSION_link_2_3"        toField=  "set_spine"/> 
      </Scene> 
    </X3D> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post personal contact information in questions. If we're going to help you, we're going to do it _here_ so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the biggest problem is that x3dom requires closing tags, not self closing i.e. change all self closed tags like this from;

```
<TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_node1" enabled="true"/>
```

to;

```
<TouchSensor DEF="TOUCH_SENSOR_node1" enabled="true"></TouchSensor>
```

I didnt look closely at the rest of it but hope this helps.